Is the final flag on explicit implementation in interfaces semantically meaningless
Normally when the final flag is specified on a virtual method (sealed in c#), the method cannot be overridden in subclasses.
However for explicit implementation of interfaces in other interfaces this does not seem to be the case. For example:
interface IBase {
    //public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void
    public void DefaultImpl() {
        Console.WriteLine("IBase DefaultImpl");
    }
}
interface IDerived : IBase {

    // no newslot..presumably reusing the one declared above

    //private final hidebysig virtual instance void
    void IBase.DefaultImpl() {
        Console.WriteLine("IDerived DefaultImpl");
    }
}
interface IMoreDerived : IDerived {
    // this "overrides"
    // private final hidebysig virtual instance void
    void IBase.DefaultImpl() {
        Console.WriteLine("IMoreDerived DefaultImpl");
    }
}
class MoreDerivedClass: IMoreDerived {
    // this "overrides" too - uncomment to see
    //public final hidebysig newslot virtual instance void
    //public void DefaultImpl() {
    //    Console.WriteLine("MoreDerivedClass DefaultImpl");
    //}
}

This all compiles without issues (please note the IL summary of the flags in the comments above the methods definitions).
When we test we see that the IDerived implementation wasn't very final at all (to be fair that's clear from lack of compilation errors).
IBase iBase = new MoreDerivedClass();
iBase.DefaultImpl(); // "IMoreDerived DefaultImpl"

We could have just omitted final and had virtual methods with no newslot to disambiguate between new EIMIs and new default interface method implementations (see IL of IBase method declaration).
The only relevant official info I was able to find was from the ECMA-335 CLI Specification Addendum

Interface methods are allowed to MethodImpl other interface methods
the interface requires (but we require the MethodImpls to be final to
keep things simple) - i.e. an interface is allowed to provide (or
override) an implementation of another interface's method

How are things kept simple? Is semantic meaning here sacrificed for reusing final as a marker somewhere as an implementation detail?
